DOCKER - trying to run mysql and apache both in foreground
FROM ubuntu:latest
Run <<EOF
apt update
apt install -y apache2 mysql-server php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-curl php-json php-cgi php-cli php-zip php-xml php-mbstring
apt install wget
EOF


ENV WP_DB_NAME="Btsample"
ENV WP_DB_USER="Bt"
ENV WP_DB_PASS="**********"


CMD service mysql start && apachectl -D FOREGROUND


RUN mysql <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE $WP_DB_NAME;
CREATE USER '$WP_DB_USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$WP_DB_PASS';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $WP_DB_NAME.* TO '$WP_DB_USER'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;
EOF

RUN wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf latest.tar.gz
RUN cp -R wordpress/* /var/www/html/

RUN tee /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf > /dev/null <<EOF  
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName wordpress.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
EOF

RUN  rm var/www/html/index.html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]


Are you asking about the "mysql" client?  or the "mysqld" server?  Apache should be background.  To have two things in the "foreground", launch them in separate "terminals".

rick , thanks for replying , actually I am trying to build  a docker file for wordpress , where I also need mysql and apache and php for it but the problem here is to run both mysql and apache in foreground , i am able to run  apache  in foreground by CMD [apachectl -D foreground] but not in the case of mysql which is required to create database and user ,means mysql should be running to create databases and users , so what should I do to keep mysql running

I don't see the need for either apache or mysql being in the "foreground".  Do you have some reference that recommends that?

actually , I have a task and the task to build an image of wordpress in docker in 1 go, the rule is i don't have to open that container of that image for starting my apache and mysql ,and keeping them both alive while building the image , and it is giving me hard time ,
